# One way web socket communication?

Tags: python, sockets, websocket

I was reading about the [Python `websocket-client` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client/) and realized that, to receive data, we have to start a connection:

```
from websocket import create_connection
ws = create_connection("ws://echo.websocket.org/")
print "Received " + ws.recv() + "..."
```

What if I just need a one-way connection? Say a Python script is running on my laptop, and it periodically sends messages to a local web server.

To receive messages, the web server would have to start a connection, but starting a connection requires a URL to connect to. My Python script is not a web server, so it lacks a URL. How could the web server receive messages from the script?

I tried to let the server listen for clients to connect with it via

```
ws = websocket.WebSocket()
while 1:
  print 'received "' + ws.recv()
```

However, I get an error.

```
in _recv
    bytes = self.io_sock.recv(bufsize)
error: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected
```

That error output leads me to believe that the server needs to connect in order to receive.

Comment: *"To receive messages, the web server would have to start a connection"* - no, the web server just needs to listen for the client to make a connection with it. The client does so exactly as you show in your example. Once they have the connection, you can send messages either way, both ways or not at all.

Comment: Thanks, but how can the server use the websockets API to listen for client connections without having to connect with anything itself?

Thank you for the edits. :)

Comment: How does a web server listen for *any* connection? The library you link to is explicitly a *client* implementation.

Comment: Post-edit: again, that's a **client library**. You also need WS support on whatever server you're using.

Answer (score 1):

If you would want one way connection to the server, you could just listen on plain socket or use UDP or use HTTP requests ore any other TCP protocol.